# Como usar un dropdown en bootstrap

Tags: html5, bootstrap-4

Hola tengo el siguiente codigo html:

```
<div class="ui compact selection dropdown">
<i class="dropdown icon"></i>
<div class="text">Compacto</div>
<div class="menu">
<div class="item">A</div>
<div class="item">B</div>
<div class="item">C</div>
</div>
</div>
```

El dropdown no funciona, alguna opinion sobre esto?

Answer (score 0):

te recomiendo que uses mejor una lista de ves de div para crear el dropdown.
Puedes usar el siguiente codigo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Dropdown</h2>
  <p>La clase .dropdown se usa para indicar un menú desplegable.

Use la clase .dropdown-menu para construir el menú desplegable.

Para abrir el menú desplegable, use un botón o un enlace con una clase de .dropdown-toggle y data-toggle = "dropdown".</p>                                          
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Compacto
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```